# Disabling all execution for a period of time

Tags: c#, wpf

I need to disable all execution of any event (click) for a period of time after l click a button. At that particular period, no matter how many buttons I click the functions of buttons will not be executed. I cannot use the `Thread.Sleep()` because it only delays the execution, the function of the button still being executed. Does any1 can help? My code is here:

```
int delay = 2000; //unusable as it is just delaying the execution of clicked button.
public void PressCOM(string key)
    {
        if (key == "PressSc")
        { 
            PressAndRelease(key);
            PressAndRelease("C");

            Thread.Sleep(delay);
        }
```

Comment: You should wonder if you're not doing something wrong if this is an requirement..

Comment: @Kolky - I thought that as well, but customers sometimes ask for weird stuff :)   It would be more reasonable if the buttons were re-enabled when whatever 'operation that must not be reentered' is completed.  Either that or queueing up input to the operation so that the buttons don't need to be disabled at all.

Comment: Yes, l'm not doing something wrong by disabling the Click for buttons after a Click of a button. It only involve a small amount of time. I want this code for some user interface purpose.

Comment: But the way you are trying to do it is most definitely wrong. Just disable your button, then it can't be clicked anymore. And after the code that runs when the button is clicked is finished, enable it again.

Answer (score 4):

Sleeping on the main thread is a bad idea anyway.

You will have to built in some logic concerning the buttons to either:

- disable them
- ignore clicks

Use a Boolean property that is reset by a timer.

Comment: Can you disable the whole form/panel/whatever that the buttons are parented on?  Not sure on wpf.

Answer (score 2):

Disabling and showing a "Please Wait..." kind of message to the user will be a better option...

**You can Disable and enable the panels .Grids in WPF as you like**

I Usually use a `Adorner Overlay` (translucent) with a message to stop user from interacting with the UI... usually Backround worker helps to Show and Hide the overlay when required.

[This will be a Good Artice for Adorner implemtation in XAml](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/54472/Defining-WPF-Adorners-in-XAML)

hope it helps.. :)

Answer (score 2):

It's not really clear what you want to do.

It's not a really good idea to put a sleep in the main application thread. It will make your application unresponsive to all Windows messages (both originated by user or by Windows itself). Your users will fill it hanged.

If you need to disable only that button you may set its `IsEnabled` property to `false`, user won't be able to click it.

If you want to disable **all** events you can use the `IsEnabled` property of the window itself.

If to disable all controls (or just one button) isn't the right solution for you then you may use one of the followings.

Add a *state* variable (or a simple flag). In all your event handlers you'll check if that variable is true or not (you'll change it with a timer). Something like:

```
if (!_canHandleMouseClicks)
   return false;
```

Disable all buttons and re-enable them after a period of time:

```
private static IEnumerable<Button> FindAllButtons(DependencyObject obj)
{
    if (obj == null)
        return null;

    int childrenCount = VisualTreeHelper.GetChildrenCount(obj);
    for (int i = 0; i < childrenCount; ++i)
    {
        DependencyObject child = VisualTreeHelper.GetChild(obj, i);

        if (child != null && child is Button)
            yield return (Button)child;

        // If you may have buttons inside buttons then uncomment these lines
        //foreach (Button childOfChild in FindAllButtons(child))
        //    yield return childOfChild;
    }
}
```

Then you can write:

```
foreach (Button button in FindAllButtons(window))
    button.IsEnabled = false; // true to re-enable
```

Comment: Thx for ur info, but my button are made up of images, so l don't think ur code can work in my case. But ur code can be used as future reference.

Answer (score 0):

A possible solution might be to show a dialog and hide the dialogs ok, cancel and close buttons. This will prevent any button from being clicked in the main-window.